# Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects If and Elif

Tags: python, dataframe, if-statement, jupyter-notebook, slice

df_13 is the main data frame
I sliced it into two df for simplicity int1 and lnppi

```
COEFF_sum=[]
if int1['PERIODID']==lnppi_ctr['PERIODID'] and int1['ITEMID']==lnppi_ctr['ITEMID']:
    COEFF_sum=lnppi_ctr['COEFF']+int1['COEFF']
elif int1['PERIODID']!=lnppi_ctr['PERIODID'] or int1['ITEMID']!=lnppi_ctr['ITEMID']:
    COEFF_sum=lnppi_ctr['COEFF']
```

I am getting  "Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects", does anyone know why?

Comment: Your `elif` shouldn't be indented.

Comment: when I corrected it, I am getting the following column "Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects".

Comment: You should fix the question to reflect this new information: your question still says there's invalid syntax, but it seems like that's no longer your problem.

Comment: Also, if you could also share what you are trying to do. I feel like you are taking a non-set based approach to set-based data and, as a result, are comparing series to series instead of "each value in this series" to "each corresponding value in this other series" like I believe you intended to do.

Comment: @JNevill Both dataframes are sliced from df13. But the Row size is different, which I believe is my current issue

Answer (score 0):

Your indentation for elif appears to be wrong: it should be on the same level as the initial if conditional.

Comment: Please, write the correct code, here.